# How do I render an element as many times as a value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some value stored in state like this

```
const [numberOfPages, setNumberOfPages] = useState(0);
```

Currently I have hard coded option tags as follows

```
  <select name="pageswitch" id="pageswitch">
    <option value="1">Page 1</option>
    <option value="2">Page 2</option>
    <option value="3">Page 3</option>
  </select>
```

I want those option tags to be dynamic . as in if the ***numberOfPages*** value is a certain number I want to return just as many option elements. Like if the number is two I want to show page1 and page2 e.t.c

How can I do that?

Comment: [https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an array (or an iterable)

```
<select name="pageswitch" id="pageswitch">
{
  Array.from({ length: numberOfPages }).map((_, i) => 
    <option key={i} value={i + 1}>Page {i + 1}</option>
  )
}
</select>
```

Comment: Good, but 3 issues. It should be `i + 1` so that counting is 1 based, not 0 based, and I think you should use curlies `value={i +1}` and also add a key prop. So `<option key={\`option${1 + 1}\`} value={i + 1}>Page {i + 1}</option>`

Comment: @spender you are 100% right

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it works but i dont get why

Comment: @AmosMachora which part you don't understand?